# My streaming json string throws an error in my jasonlite fromJSON R script function

Tags: json, r, azure, parsing, streaming

I have a streaming json from a simulator coming in and fail in R script within AzureML Execute R script.

I get the following error

> "An exception was encountered while invoking the Azure ML function TelcoMLFunction with endpoint URL HTTP error code: BadRequest. Reason phrase: Bad Request\r\nResponse Headers:\r\nx-ms-request-id: 7fc44229-bfa0-41a0-9692-91849b67d10a\r\nDate: Tue, 05 Sep 2017 04:45:14 GMT\r\nETag: \"1ba412a1-68e5-4561-8290-d6ae955900f6\"\r\nServer: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0\r\nResponse Body:\r\n{\"error\":{\"code\":\"LibraryExecutionError\",\"message\":\"Module execution encountered an internal library error.\",\"details\":
>   {\"code\":\"FailedToEvaluateRScript\",\"target\":\"Execute R Script Piped > RPackage)\",\"message\":\"The following error occurred during evaluation of R script: R_tryEval: return error: Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.\n                                       NA\n                     (right here) ------^\n\"}]}}\r\nSee Azure Machine Learning REST API Error Codes for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn913081.aspx\r\n\r\n",`

I've been searching google for every possible post with jsonlite failures and the following error code and I can't get it to work. The tricky part of it is that if I feedin json strings in tsv file format, my script works, but as soon as the streaming json data comes into the R script module, it fails with the above error.

my json format is

```
{"RecordType":"MO","SystemIdentity":"d0","FileNum":"0","SwitchNum":"UK","CallingNum":"012392572","CallingIMSI":"466922202613463","CalledNum":"567881498","CalledIMSI":"466923100807296","DateS":"20170814","TimeS":null,"TimeType":3,"CallPeriod":0,"CallingCellID":null,"CalledCellID":null,"ServiceType":"b","Transfer":1,"IncomingTrunk":null,"OutgoingTrunk":"409","MSRN":"886932428687","CalledNum2":null,"FCIFlag":null,"callrecTime":"2017-08-14T23:57:16.0000000Z","EventProcessedUtcTime":"2017-08-14T23:57:16.2330567Z","PartitionId":1,"EventEnqueuedUtcTime":"2017-08-14T23:57:17.7740000Z"}
```

My code is written like this

```
df <- maml.mapInputPort(1) # class: data.frame
df <- df[[1]]
df <- gsub('""', '"', df)
df <- lapply(df, fromJSON)
df <- lapply(df, function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- "NA"
  unlist(x)
})
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(df), nrow=length(df), ncol=25, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I've tried so many different permutations of `json` parsing for months, but I still can't get it work. Please help!

Thank you,

Comment: It's definitely not happy with the JSON string it's trying to parse, and if I'm reading the error correctly it's something to do with, or just in front of, the caret ^. Control characters are not valid in a string in JSON's eyes (see www.json.org) and there may be one hiding in there too. Either way, is it possible to pipe the stream to a file so we can inspect what's coming out of your simulator?

Comment: Thanks Tim for your response. I dumped the output as a .json output. I get the multiple lines of json i specified above. During the ingestion process, it gets converted to avro > Json with UTF-8 format. I also received the following error \r\nparse error: premature EOF\r\n                                       {\"RecordType\":\"MO\"\r\n (right here) ------^\r\n\r\n\r\nparse error: premature EOF\r\n {\"RecordType\":\"MO\"\r\n                     (right here) ------^\r\n
parse error: premature EOF
                  {"RecordType":"MO"
(right here) ------^
parse error: premature EOF

Comment: What is it that's actually throwing that parse error, is it when you try and execute your R script in Azure? It's worth opening up the .json in a text editor and checking it's valid json (you can post a snippet in the question too) but as you've got it open in a text editor, have a look for any 'hidden' characters that aren't valid json and might not paste here properly

Comment: 1. Is the JSON you're reading in actually JSON, or ndjson? 2. What code are you using to read in the JSON; are you using`jsonlite::stream_in()`? 3. The caret symbol `^` is part of the error message from `jsonlite`, pointing to where the invalid json character is. 4. The JSON snippet you've provided is valid, and can be read in using `fromJSON`. As it stands, we can't reproduce your error given the data you've provided.

Comment: 1. It is not ndjson. 2.I am using jsonlite and fromJSON. You are correct. I can read it using RStudio with a static file, but it fails when the streaming JSON come in to Rscript within AzureML. Thanks for looking into this though.